# NullPointerException in TokenEndpoint

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, jpql

LE: I initially thought this was related to the JPQL query - please see below.

I'm struggling with an issue and I can't seem to find any solution for it. I am trying to locate a user in the database. The search criteria is the username OR email address. The user might not have a username so I am always getting a `NullPointerException` in my `CrudRepository`. I've tried both a JPQL and a native query but I always get the same.

I can successfully run the native query in MySQL Workbench - in Java it throws an exception.

Here's my repository when using the native query:

```
@Query(value = "select * from users u where " +
        "(u.username is not null and u.username = :queryString) or " +
        "(u.email_address is not null and u.email_address = :queryString)",
        nativeQuery = true)
Optional<User> findByEmailAddressOrUsername(@Param("queryString") String queryString);
```

And with JPQL:

```
@Query("select u from user u where " +
        "(u.emailAddress is not null and u.emailAddress = ?1) or " +
        "(u.username is not null and u.username = ?1)")
Optional<User> findByEmailAddressOrUsername(String queryString);
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: You should attach exception stacktrace to your question

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, seems like I finally found the issue. It was way more subtle than I expected. It had nothing to do with the JPQL or SQL queries, they were perfectly fine. The problem was actually in my custom `TokenEnhancer` where I had a check on my `UserDetails`. Since `getUsername()` returns null (because some users do not have usernames this would trigger the `NullPointerException` that I've mentioned earlier.